# Use Morera's Theorem to construct an entire function $g(z)$ with the following property

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Use Morera's Theorem to construct an entire function $g(z)$ with the following property:

$g(z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{sinh\ z}{z},\ z\neq 0\\
\\
1,\ z= 0
\end{cases}$

The thing here is that I dont understand the question, what exactly do they want me to construct here ?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated

Comment: The function is already "constructed".  You just said what it is.  Maybe you want to use Morera's theorem to prove that function is holomorphic?  It would be easier to show it directly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts, sorry bout the question, guess it's just bad phrasing

Comment: You may want to consider editing your question if this isn't what you're asking.